# Error while trying to start PostgreSQL installed via Homebrew: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have recently installed PostgreSQL on my Mac via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)). (I may have already had it installed; it was not running.)

```
brew install postgres
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Now I am trying to start it with `launchctl`:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

...but I am getting an error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Operation not permitted

What does this error mean? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Apparently brew/OSX [sometimes requires a restart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248693/watchman-com-github-facebook-watchman-plist-operation-not-permitted) before everything works. Before we all get into the problem-solving-mode: Did you try [turning it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)?

Comment: Rebooting doesn't change anything.

Comment: Agreed, rebooting did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It could be that you're using `launchctl` inside of [Tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) or [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

Tmux and Screen are terminal multiplexers that spawn multiple "screens" that you can easily switch between in a single terminal.

For some reason unknown to me, running `launchctl` inside of Tmux never works, and emits the error `Operation not permitted`. Run it inside of a normal shell and it will probably work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I was using `tmux`! However, I seem to be running into a different issue now. Using `launchctl` outside of `tmux`, I see "Operation already in progress", yet I cannot connect to Postgres.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem through some combination of `unload`ing the launch agent plist, removing the old installation of Postgres, moving the old data directory, and reinstalling the latest version.

Comment: Finally i stumbled on this and answered why I have been struggling with for more than a month . Finally i know the reason thanks for this...

Comment: A solution for this is to use reattach-to-user-session as mentioned here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41412/using-tmux-and-pbpaste-pbcopy-and-launchctl in your .tmux.conf

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps you may need to take:

Remove a previous installation of PostgreSQL:

```
brew remove postgres
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Install the new version:

```
brew install postgres
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

The data from your previous installation will need to be upgraded to be compatible with PostgreSQL 9.4+: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html

It seems like you need two installations of PostgreSQL in order to upgrade your database, and I didn't care to bother with that, so I just recreated the database with the new version:

```
mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/old-postgres
initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Now launch PostgreSQL (outside of `tmux` if you are using that):

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Check the logs for any issues:

```
tail /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```